# I am unable to create a connection in Oracle Sql Developer in Macbook air m2

Tags: oracle, networking, io, connection, adapter

An error was encountered performing the requested operation:

IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection (CONNECTION_ID=ttQn+vElQMiIMuRuCPEntw==)

Vendor code 17002

i am unable to create a connection Oracle sql developer in mackbook air m2

Comment: You were unable to create a connection to...what? And where is the database you're trying to connect to?

Comment: Hi JeffSmith, I usually work in MySql database but I  am new to Oracle SQL developer and I don't know how to configure oracle SQL developer I just installed it and trying to create connection in that but getting error like this IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection (CONNECTION_ID=ttQn+vElQMiIMuRuCPEntw==)

Vendor code 17002

Comment: It sounds like you only installed SQL Developer, that's not enough. You also need a database to connect to. See if this helps https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2021/02/im-a-student-studying-oracle-and-i-need-a-database-help/